# Yii2 - Login not persisted

Tags: authentication, yii2, cas

i'm trying to implement an external login (based on central authentication service) in a yii2.0 basic application. Once connected, i use a table of the database to detect the role of user.
In the siteController i set the connexion information by:

```
            Yii::$app->user->login($model->getUser(), 0);
            return $this->goHome();
```

Value is ok (tested with var_dump).

But when i go back to main menu i am still considered as guest (Yii::$app->user->identity is NULL).
In my web.php configuration:

```
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\ReprUser',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'enableSession' => true,
    ],
```

I've check my custom user class implements IdentityInterface.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean with external login? do you mean you're going to a different service/site?

Comment: CAS is external from my Yii application. User connect on CAS, application get the login id and check in yii application the autorizations for this user.

Comment: What if you try to login, go to any page (or refresh current one) and then go to external website and go back to Yii2? Will it also show as a guest?

Comment: I can't. In my yii controller i call the external login which respond well. I'm using this to populate my identity with Yii::$app->user->login(). When i go back to main page ($this->goHome()), Yii::$app->user has lost my identity.